# problems with csrf_token

Tags: django, forms, django-csrf

I'm doing wiki in django tutorial and in tutorial earlier version of django is used where csrf token is not compulsory. I've added {% csrf_token %} to the form, however I'm not sure what to do in the views. Please help.

Here's the form:

```
<form method = "POST" action="/wikicamp/{{ page_name }}/save/">{% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name = "content" rows="20" cols="60">{{ content }}</textarea><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Page"/>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def view_page(request, page_name):
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return render_to_response("create.html", {"page_name" : page_name})

    return render_to_response("view.html", {"page_name" : page_name,
                                            "content" : page.content})

def edit_page(request, page_name):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
        contents = page.content
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        content = ""
    return render_to_response("edit.html", {"page_name" : page_name,
                                            "content" : content}, c)


def save_page(request, page_name):
    content = request.POST["content"]
    try:
        page = Page.objects.get(pk=page_name)
        page.content = content
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        page = Page(name = page_name, content = content)
    page.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect("/wikicamp/" + page_name + "/")
```

here's the error

```
TypeError at /wikicamp/start/edit/
pop expected at least 1 arguments, got 0
```

Comment: please specify your error. It's not clear to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't quite understood step 3 [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/): you need to use RequestContext to ensure that the context processor is run.

```
return render_to_response("edit.html", {"page_name" : page_name,
                                        "content" : content},
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

With that, you don't need the `c.update(csrf(request))` bit.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything more.

Just place `{% csrf_token %}` into your form and send it via POST.

All other stuff will be done inside `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`.

You should enable it in your `settings.py` (if you haven't done this):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (`django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware`,)
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (`django.core.context_processors.csrf`,)
```

Last line is not required if you use `RequestContext` (not a simple `Context`) in your templates (Note: `render_to_response()` uses `Context` when `direct_to_template()` uses `RequestContext`)

Comment: Doesn't work. If I only put csrf_token into the form and send it via POST I still get "Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."

Comment: I've edited my answer. Sorry, I haven't noticed that you're using `render_to_response()`. it's tricky function, I had similar problem with it.