# "pop expected at least 1 argument" error

Tags: python, django

I am getting 
`pop expected at least 1 arguments, got 0` without any clue why I get it.

#### models.py

```
class preset_list(models.Model):
    VIEWS = (
        ('1', 'X'),
        ('2', 'Y'),
    )
    query_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=VIEWS)
```

#### view.py

```
list1 = models.preset_list()

return render_to_response('services.html', 
                              {'array':json.dumps(data, cls=SpecialEncoder)},
                              {'list1':list1}    
                               )
```

I cant even get to `HTML` because it give me an error moment I comment out `list1`.

Comment: i am not even using `csrf_token`

Comment: A side note: `{'array':json.dumps(data, cls=SpecialEncoder)},
                              {'list1':list1}` should be `{'array':json.dumps(data, cls=SpecialEncoder), 'list1':list1}`

Comment: Also, `list1 = models.preset_list()` does not make sense. Are you trying to create a new object pro `present_list`

Comment: @rodling Look at answers given here and the problem of the author.

Comment: yea fair enough, I flagged it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what `list1` is supposed to do, but you shouldn't be passing it as a third argument: it should be in the same dict as `array`.

```
return render_to_response('services.html', 
                          {'array':json.dumps(data, cls=SpecialEncoder),
                          'list1':list1}    
                           )
```

Comment: complete missed that, silly mistake! must have copy/pasted it without looking

Answer (score 2):

If you only have the `return` statement in your view and you still ave the error, then it comes from the `render_to_response` call. Indeed, the  thirs argument of the function is the `context_instance` and you replace it with the dict `{'list1':list}`, which make the rendering fails.
I suppose you want to add this list in your first dict:

```
return render_to_response('services.html', 
                          {'array':json.dumps(data, cls=SpecialEncoder), 'list1':list})
```

Duplicate (kind of) this thread: [problems with csrf_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678231/problems-with-csrf-token)